# Mathjax fonts ttf file link

Tags: fonts, amsmath

Long time ago, I was a regular attendee of math.stackexchange and then probably from the meta site, I found a web link (probably github link) to lots of mathjax fonts '.ttf'  files for my pc.
Those fonts were much helpful while math typesetting in Ms-word etc. for simple documentations.

But, today, I searched web for the .ttf file mathjax font like Mathjax_Math, Mathjax_Main, Mathjax_AMS, Mathjax_Caligraphic etc, but cannot find that webpage link anywhere. Also I have deleted my stackexchange a/c long ago, so, can't run the search through the site thoroughly!

Someone please post the link of all those mathjax fonts for pc.
Thanks.

Comment: Downvoting is ok, but at least provide the link. I myself will delete the post after getting that link. I Googled this, but can't find the link.

Comment: Mathjax is no used or supported on this site. So what exactly are you expecting us to provide? (I did not down vote). As mathjax does not use latex and friends it is not something we support or generally help with here.